# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS /dev/sdb1 corruption , every time i close laptop lid

Tags: 16.04, laptop, lts, lid

After i close the laptop lid , and open it again , ubuntu ran into so many problems.

For example , i can't Search in apps ,open firefox or open "About This Computer".Firefox shows a crash message.

So i restarted laptop , but /dev/sdb1 corruption error occured.I Fixed it by fsck /dev/sdb1 , and all problems solved.but again when i close the laptop lid , the problems has occured again.

My laptop is "Asus K550JX" and ubuntu is installed on a 16GB USB 3.0 Flash.How can i solve it? Thanks.

Comment: The only fix is to NOT use suspend (or closing the lid). External flash drives or even HDDs get corrupted that way. Consider installing in the internal drive to avaoid this.

Comment: Do you have your USB 3 flash drive plugged into a USB 3 port, or a USB 2 port? When you formatted the USB flash drive, what format did you choose? Why are you running Ubuntu from a flash drive anyway? Do you also run Windows (dual-boot configuration)? Cheers, Al

Comment: @CelticWarrior Yes i disabled suspend mode in power settings , but it is not what i want.But i think there should be a way for solve it.

Comment: @heynnema no , USB3 Flash On USB3 Port.Format: EXT4.I use flash drive because i have windows on hard drive , and for preventing from some issues.

Comment: For testing purposes, if you plug the flash drive into a USB 2.0 port, does the same corruption occur? Cheers, Al

Comment: @heynnema Yes , same.

Comment: Would you be, by chance, accessing the Ubuntu flash from Windows, using a software tool or driver (as Windows doesn't know how to deal with EXT4 file systems)? Cheers, Al

Comment: Well spotted, heynnema. Actually just booting Windows with the USB inserted is probably enough to generate errors.